# Cloud computing pricing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I’m looking to use a cloud computing instance which will give me best value for my particular use case.

What I need to do is fire off a script periodically which performs some actions via selenium.

My questions are:

1. Will the packages installed be “remembered” if I reboot the instance?
2. Does the instance even need to be rebooted sometimes?
3. Do I get persistent storage or something else?
4. Am I charged when my instance is running but idle (between cron jobs)?

Any recommendations on which type of service would provide best value for my use case.

EDIT: I made some edits because I offended people by mentioning specific vendors and asking about pricing. The question probably could have been worded better initially but what I really wanted to know was which cloud computing solutions would be best value for a particular use case which seems to be a bit niche.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pricing of off-site vendor services and not a programming related question. If you have pricing questions, contact that vendor directly and ask them. We are not their sales or support staff. The [help] has more information regarding what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here

Answer (score 1):

I'm with GCP Support team, so I will provide information on Google Cloud’s part.

Google Cloud Compute Engine offers a free usage for an amount up to a specific [limit](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#freeusage).

> Will the packages installed be “remembered” if I reboot the instance? Do I get persistent storage or something else?

When you create a new VM instance you get assigned at least 10 Gb of persistent disk. Everything that is stored on that disk will stay there even in case of rebooting the instance.

> Does the instance even need to be rebooted sometimes?

Instances doesn’t have to be rebooted unless you want so. However, occasionally they get rebooted automatically by the Google Compute Engine service.

> Am I charged when my instance is running but idle (between cron jobs)?

You are charged for the instance when it is up and running. You can find more information about Google Cloud Compute pricing [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing).

To have an approximation of what you will be paying, based on what you will be using, you can use [GCP Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found a couple of suitable options for running a selenium script a few times a day.

1) GCP, which as mentioned in another answer has a free tier.

2) AWS provides lambdas for running code without needing to provision servers. They also provide a free tier and I found some pre-compiled AWS lambda packages using Python + Selenium and some pretty clear instructions on how to get them running in AWS on a schedule: https://github.com/ryfeus/lambda-packs.